# Display custom tooltip on highcharts legend

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I would like to know if is it possible to add a custom tooltip on highchart legend during on hover event.

I'm currently able to detect the event but i have no idea on how create the tooltip using highcharts.

My code :

```
$('.highcharts-legend text').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).hover(function() {
            alert('Display my custom tooltip');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi James, there is no answer...

Comment: Hmm, I've retracted my close vote as the answer isn't very detailed. I'd suggest using jQuery UI or something similar, as you're already using jQuery. jQuery UI has a `tooltip()` function.

Comment: I prefer to know if it's possible using highcharts before but no I haven't tried it yet :) thx

Comment: Hi, i think this is not possible by using highcharts themself. They do not have a tooltip on the legend, and you can only use the functions they already have implemened. That is why you can bind the event and do what you need.

Comment: I'm sorry, but imho my answer is very detailed.. :) However is buggy (closures - just fixed). Just get elements and attach mouseover/mouseout events.

Comment: Yes Pawel, i am using your answer with jquery-ui tooltip function and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone through the HighCharts docs for this and cannot find anything that would help you implement a tooltip on legend. You will most probably need to use a JQuery tooltip plugin to get your legend on hover tooltip.